# Does this linear recurrence relation have a solution?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

It seems to me that this recurrence relation has no solution. The answer I get does not prove true for all of the initial conditions.
I have also tried solving it from Wolfram Alpha, which says no solutions exist yet my marking scheme has an answer.

$$2a_{n+3}=a_{n+2}+2a_{n+1}-a_n$$
given that $a_0=0, a_1 = 1, a_2 = 2$

Answer in the marking scheme is:

$$a_{n}=5/2 - (1/6)^n - 8/3(1/2)^n$$

[**Edit**: I found my mistake; see my answer below.]

Comment: This is a fairly standard sort of problem, generally solved by considering the [Characteristic Polynomial](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Characteristic_polynomial) of the recursion.

Comment: Please type your question like in my edit above in future. Pictures make it less accessible for people to access. Put everything in one place

Comment: Thanks for the tip

Comment: The Mathematica command `RSolve[{2a[n+3]==a[n+2]+2 a[n+1]-a[n],a[0]==0, a[1]==1, a[2]==2},a[n],n]` produces $$a_n=\frac{1}{3} 2^{-n-1} \left((-2)^n+15\
    2^n-16\right).$$

Comment: There is absolutely no matching between the question and the marking scheme, and it is wrong that Alpha cannot solve. Double check your statements.

Comment: If you compute the terms for $n=0,1,2$ according to the answer you report from the marking scheme, you get $a_0=-7/6$, $a_1=1$, $a_2=65/36.$ Apart from $a_1$, these don’t match the initial conditions so the marking scheme answer is wrong. (Adrian’s answer above, by contrast, entirely fulfills those conditions.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wolfram Alpha gives the correct answer and I realized I was not doing the question correctly so the answer can be found using:
$$a_n = q^n$$

The correct answer is:
$$\frac{1}{6}[(-1)^n-2^{4-n}+15]$$

Answer (score 0):

Your equation is linear, so try it with $$a_n=q^n$$
Then you will get the equation for $q$
$$2q^{n+3}=q^{n+2}+2q^{n+1}-q^n$$

Now compute $q$
Divide the whole equation by $q^n$

Comment: Yes I have tried with that my answer does not match the answer in the marking scheme

Comment: @TonyMogoa, the marking scheme is wrong.